# EmberJS nested route not getting resolved

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to construct a simple address book app in EmberJS.RC.1 build as part of learning it. My routes are not getting through the initial checks. What is the issue here?
http://jsfiddle.net/Sz6fj/

Error in console:

> **Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Cannot call get with 'id' on an undefined object** 
>   - ember-1.0.0-rc.1.js:52

### structure

```
contacts
contacts/new
contacts/<id>
contacts/<id>/edit
```

---

Code:

```
App.Router.map(function(){
  this.resource('contacts', {path: '/'}, function(){
    this.route('new', {path: '/new'});
    this.resource('contact', {path: '/:contact_id'}, function(){
      this.route('edit', {path: '/edit'});
    });//contact
  });//contacts
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you don't have a `contact_id` on the model. If you change it to the primary key (`id`) then it will work just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Sz6fj/1/

`contact_id` does have a special usage on foreign keys.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
App.Router.map(function(){
  this.resource('contacts', {path: '/'}, function(){
    this.route('new');
    this.resource('contact', {path: '/contacts/:contact_id'}, function(){
      this.route('edit');
    });
  });
});
```